# Plot Histograms in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

As we know that histogram and bar charts are two different things. I have got many different ways to plot bar charts in highcharts but I didn't get any examples for histogram plot in highcharts. Is it possible to plot histogram using highcharts, if yes, How ?

Comment: A histogram is just a column (bar) chart that represents a distribution of data.  Since it's the data that defines a histogram there nothing special highcharts can't already draw.  Here's an example from user @jlbriggs: http://jsfiddle.net/9LGVA/369/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use highcharts columns chart with reduced all paddings,

```
groupPadding: 0,
pointPadding: 0,
borderWidth: 0
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WbHsX/8/

or more complex example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9LGVA/370/