# Creating a histogram with distribution curve, where the curve series is larger than the bin series

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, data-visualization

I want to create a histogram in Highcharts. The bin series has about 8 elements.  The series for the the distribution curve has about 200 elements. Since Highcharts infers the xAxis from  the number of elements in the series, the xAxis stretches out to 200. How do I get the curve series to fit to the bin series on the xAxis?

Comment: Did you see this response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042165/plot-histograms-in-highcharts?

Comment: Yes, if the size of the series were equal, then I wouldn't have this issue. The reason the distribution curve is so large is because defined the curve much better than a series with only 8 points.

Comment: But, if the xAxis values are on the same scale it should still fit. You may need to null/zero your bins for the xAxis points with no matching data such that the 2 series use the same scale. Can you set up a representative jsFiddle?

Comment: Yeah I can. I'm currently grabbing the data via an ajax request through a web service. I can can set up an example with a hardcoded series.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/a6H6k/20/ I can't get it you render in JSfiddle, I think the the 200 element series is giving JSfiddle trouble. THe only thing I changed from my local implementation is I hardcoded the series in.

Comment: Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/Dd9Py/. You just needed to tell it what framework (I chose jQuery) and also include reference to highcharts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using 2 x axes for this.  It is far easier than trying to make the points match on a single axis.

See my `example` here:

http://jsfiddle.net/FnhRV/19/

Answer (score 2):

Well, first I advice to get familiar with Highcharts docs/tutorials. Like [this one](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes).

In general, you can manage distance between points, it's called `pointInterval`, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dd9Py/1/

When you have 8 columns, on xAxis you should have scale - according to pair [x,y] of values.

Another solution is to use two different xAxis, one for column and one for spline. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dd9Py/2/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/Dd9Py/). Things I notice is that your `xAxis` is linear - meaning that each point is plotted consecutively. So, since your `bar` series only has 8 points they are plotted int he first 8 positions. Your curve contains 200 points and are also plotted first come first served. You need to link up your xAxis so that each series is linked. What are your `xAxis` increments/categories?

Comment: Right now I'm just letting Highcharts handle it. As part of the more complex Ajax request, the categories are defined by a part of an array of bin objects returned from the request.